# How to use sshpass when loging in to remote server with Emacs / Tramp

Tags: emacs, elisp

I found a related thread that describes how to login to a remote server using `sshpass`:

```
sshpass -p '<password>' <ssh/scp command>
```

How can logging in **with password** be accomplished in Emacs / Tramp?

I presently use the following and then enter the password manually:

```
C-x C-f /ssh:user@server:/home/user/public_html/
```

I have the following function, that I access from my right-click context pop-up menu:

```lisp
(defun lawlist-remote-server-login ()
(interactive)
  (find-file "/ssh:user@server:/home/user/public_html/"))
```

Comment: Tramp should prompt you for your password if you use the regular SSH transport and the server supports password authentication. Does it not?

Comment: @Chris -- yes, I was just hoping to save a step by logging into my own shared server account without typing the password.  Something like:  `(let ((password "123456")) (find-file "/ssh:user@server:/home/user/public_html/") )`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're simply trying to avoid typing your password, but you don't want to use SSH keys, you can use an authentication file.

From [the TRAMP user manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/tramp/Password-handling.html):

> ### 4.12.1 Using an authentication file
>
> The package `auth-source.el`, originally developed in No Gnus, offers
>   the possibility to read passwords from a file, like FTP does it from
>   `~/.netrc`. The default authentication file is `~/.authinfo.gpg`, this can
>   be changed via the variable `auth-sources`.
>
> A typical entry in the authentication file would be
>
> ```
>  machine melancholia port scp login daniel password geheim
> ```
>
> The port can be any tramp method (see [Inline methods](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/tramp/Inline-methods.html#Inline-methods), see [External
>   methods](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/tramp/External-methods.html#External-methods)), to match only this method. When you omit the port, you match
>   all tramp methods.
>
> In case of problems, setting `auth-source-debug` to `t` gives useful debug
>   messages.

**Edit:**

The specific code that worked for the OP without requiring GnuPG is reproduced below.

Emacs configuration:

```lisp
(setq auth-sources '("/Users/HOME/.0.data/.0.emacs/.authinfo"))
```

And in the `.authinfo` file identified above:

```
machine 12.34.56.789 login lawlist password 12345678 port ssh
```

Comment: Mission accomplished -- thank you very much -- greatly appreciated !!!  :)  Content of **.authinfo**:  `machine 12.34.56.789 login lawlist password 12345678 port ssh`   To change the location of **.authinfo**, I used `(setq auth-sources '("/Users/HOME/.0.data/.0.emacs/.authinfo"))`

Comment: @lawlist, great! Did you also have to set up GnuPG (`gpg`)?

Comment: I tried with `gpg` two different ways -- https://gpgtools.org/ and  http://www.gnupg.org/download/ -- `(setq epg-gpg-program "/usr/local/bin/gpg")` -- I was not able to find anything on the internet explaining this error:  `Opening input file: Can't decrypt, No data (no armored data); No data (expected a packet but did not found one); Exit`  It *might* have been related to an incorrect entry in the `.authinfo.gpg` file.  I eventually found a non-gpg example that worked (above), and by that time I had uninstalled `gpg` and ended up with just a plain `.authinfo` file without the `gpg` extension.

Comment: @lawlist, great. I've updated my answer to include this information.