# Automate remote access in emacs

Tags: emacs, tramp

I'm a beginner in using **emacs**. I would like to simplify the ssh access to a remote server via tramp. My first naive trial was recording a macro. However, calling the saved macro after a re-start of emacs I receive a "`byte-code: Args out of range: [], 0`" message. Instead one can also defining a environment variable

```
(setenv "SECRET" "/ssh:user@secret.tld:")
```

Is there a better solution? I would like to have a definition where I type `M-x connection-name` and get my pre-defined ssh-tramp-connection set up.

Comment: Chris previously helped me out on a similar issue for `find-file` -- here is the link to that related thread:  http://stackoverflow.com/a/22974359/2112489

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably the easiest solution is to configure each of your desired hosts in `~/.ssh/config`, e.g.

```ini
Host some-name               # The friendly name of this host
HostName real-host.name.tld  # The host to connect to
User foo                     # The user to connect as

Host other
HostName 123.45.67.89
User bar
```

This has the benefit that you can now `ssh some-name` or `ssh other` on the command line, and when you try to edit a file using Tramp's SSH you can type

```
/ssh:
```

and then tab-complete for `some-name` or `other`. If you use `ido` you'll get automatically prompted without tab completing.

There are [many other options that can be used in your `~/.ssh/config` file](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=ssh_config&sektion=5), like setting default tunnels and tweaking authentication modes.

If Tramp doesn't respond properly when you tab-complete, [set the completion function for SSH like this](http://www.gnu.org/software/tramp/#Customizing-Completion) (this should be the default value):

```lisp
(tramp-set-completion-function "ssh"
 '((tramp-parse-sconfig "/etc/ssh_config")
   (tramp-parse-sconfig "~/.ssh/config")))
```

Finally, if you want not to be prompted for your password, I recommend using [SSH key-based authentication](http://www.openbsd.org/cgi-bin/man.cgi?query=ssh-keygen).